# Creating LineString from points by group of time period using SQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, order, st-makeline

I have a serie of GPS points with dates and a state ('flying' or 'grown') from different individuals.

I would like to get lines from those points by individual, grouped by state BUT still ordered by dates, without mixing old "flying" points with recent "flying" points.

Here an example of a dataset (with dates as an integer):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES
    ('A', 'grown', '1', ST_MakePoint(0,0)),
    ('A', 'flying', '2', ST_MakePoint(0,1)),
    ('A', 'flying', 3, ST_MakePoint(0,2)),
    ('A', 'flying', 4, ST_MakePoint(0,3)),
    ('A', 'grown', 5, ST_MakePoint(0,4)),
    ('A', 'grown', 6, ST_MakePoint(0,5)),
    ('B', 'flying', 7, ST_MakePoint(0,8)),
    ('B', 'grown', 8, ST_MakePoint(0,9))
    ) AS t (find, state, date, geom)
```

I would like these rank values (in bold the tricky part):

| ind | state | date | geom | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | **grown** | 1 | POINT (0 0) | **1** |
| A | flying | 2 | POINT (0 1) | 2 |
| A | flying | 3 | POINT (0 2) | 2 |
| A | flying | 4 | POINT (0 3) | 2 |
| A | **grown** | 5 | POINT (0 4) | **3** |
| A | **grown** | 6 | POINT (0 5) | **3** |
| B | flying | 7 | POINT (0 8) | 4 |
| B | grown | 8 | POINT (0 9) | 5 |

I tried to use the `RANK()` Windows function but it still groups similar states (e.g. 'flying') altogether, although those flying points are separated by a series of 'grown' points.

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh I remember this seemingly simple thing driving me absolutely *insane* - years ago, before *StackExchange*...

To get a grouping of sequentially (equal) values inside a *window* of *ordered* rows, you need a *more or less* adapted form of this generic sub-query:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ([PARTITION BY  t.<partition_column_1>, ... ] ORDER BY t.<sequence_or_primary_ordering>)
  - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [t.<partition_column_1>, ...,] t.<sequentially_altering_values> ORDER BY t.<sequence_or_primary_order_column>) AS _seq
FROM
  <tbl> AS t
;
```

*Note the use of `[]` to indicate **optional** clauses.*

where

- `t.<sequence_or_primary_ordering>` refers to a column holding ***strictly incremental values*** used as means to derive a primary order of rows (if the respective column is a *numeric* type already, the `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate a surrogate *numeric* is not needed)

  - *your `"date"` column*
- `t.<sequentially_altering_values>` refers to the column that you want to ***create sequential groupings*** over

  - *your `"state"` column*
- `t.<partition_column_n> [OPTIONAL]` refers to ***any other *window partitioning* columns*** needed to produce unambiguous combinations of the above

  - *your `ind` column*

---

Stitching this together to fit your setup:

```
SELECT
  g.ind, g."status",
  ST_MakeLine(g.geom ORDER BY g."date") AS geom
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.*,
        t.dte  -- since this is a numeric value already we don't need to create a surrogate sequence as in the generic query above
      - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ind, t."status" ORDER BY t."date") AS _seq
    FROM
      <tbl> AS t
  ) AS g
GROUP BY
    g.ind, g."status", g._seq
ORDER BY
    g.ind, MIN(g."date")
;
```

to aggregate your *Point*s into *LineString*s accordingly, or

```
SELECT
  g.*,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY g.ind, g._seq) AS "rank"
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.*,
        t.dte  -- since this is a numeric value already we don't need to create a surrogate sequence as in the generic query above
      - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ind, t."status" ORDER BY t."date") AS _seq
    FROM
      <tbl> AS t
  ) AS g
ORDER BY
  "rank"
;
```

to get the output in your question.

Comment: Just tried to search for this...didn't even know how to. Found a few answers after a while, some having the same concept, some using others. Looks like this approach here is top, next to using a custom function.

Comment: For reading pleasure: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/form-groups-of-consecutive-rows-with-same-value

Comment: @JGH thx., that's the one I found, too. Lol, and yes, Erwins answer basically holds or references every single possible solution there is in all of SQL and you can read about them 'till the end of time...

Comment: Excellent! Thx a lot!! I spent so much time on that issue...